# Restlet with HTTPS (JAR missing)

Tags: https, jetty, restlet, simplehttpserver

I'm currently trying to run my server through HTTPS protocol but I can't figure out which .JAR file is missing (.JAR included are listed below):

package restlethttps;

```
   import org.restlet.Component;
   import org.restlet.Server;
   import org.restlet.data.Parameter;
   import org.restlet.data.Protocol;
   import org.restlet.util.Series;

   public class RestletHTTPS { 
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        // Create a new Component.
        Component component = new Component();

        // Add a new HTTPS server listening on port 8183       
        Server server = component.getServers().add(Protocol.HTTPS, 8082);
        Series<Parameter> parameters = server.getContext().getParameters();

        //parameters.add("sslContextFactory", "org.rest.ext.ssl.PkixSslContextFactory");
        parameters.add("keystorePath", "path...\\serverX.jks");
        parameters.add("keystorePassword", <password>);
        parameters.add("keyPassword", <password>);
        //parameters.add("keystoreType", "JKS");

        // Attach the sample application.
        component.getDefaultHost().attach("/get", new RestletHTTPSApplication());

        // Start the component.
        component.start();
    }
}
```

-JAR included:

- org.restlet.jar
- org.restlet.ext.ssl.jar
- com.noelios.restlet.ext.simple_3.1.jar
- com.noelios.restlet.ext.ssl.jar
- org.restlet-2.0.0.jar
- org.simpleframework-3.1.3.jar
- org.simpleframework.jar
- jsslutils-0.5.jar
- org.restlet.ext.jetty.jar

Comment: Can you include a stack trace?